# When software rots, what property of the system changes?

Tags: maintainability

Software rots. Or at least ages. Software development methodologies may slow down this process, but eventually almost any software system becomes so hard to maintain that a reimplementation is inevitable.

But what is that thing that gets worse with time called? Integrity? Cohesion? Entropy? The amount of technical debt? Is there an agreed upon name for that property getting worse that causes that changes in maintainability?

Comment: I'm for technical debt.

Comment: You can call it "quality of the source code" or [Software Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_entropy), that would enclose pretty much everything which can become worse by constant maintenance. However, this is still opinionated (and I am not a fan of "technical debt", sounds too metaphoric too me and can be too easily misinterpreted.)

Comment: @DocBrown Agreed, personally I find "software entropy" most appropriate too, and though technical debt is a useful metaphor for project management, I would not consider it being a property of the system at all. However, I haven't seen people using the term "software entropy" often, hence my question.

Comment: I'm dubious of the conclusion "reimplementation is inevitable."  I've seen projects go on for decades using little more than refactoring.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Sure, that statement is an oversimplification, since its validity depends on many factors like project size, complexity, environment, technology, etc. A complete reimplementation from scratch is most often economically not feasible. Nevertheless, in order to maintain a more or less constant level of maintainability, with time, larger refactorings become necessary, and at least some parts or aspects of the system will have to be reimplemented entirely. And this phenomenon seems to be universal. Maybe I am wrong, but at least [I am not the only one](http://bit.ly/1Nzkl5N).

Answer (score 6):

Some large software are rotting quite slowly, because a significant part of them becomes redesigned/reimplemented/refactored from time to time.

Take for example the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler. It is 28 years old, has more than 13 millions lines of source code (and measuring its size is challenging; depending on the tools you are using you could get a size of 20MLOC), and is still alive. I don't know what parts of it are older than 10 years, but certainly some of them are (e.g. its garbage collector, or its pass manager, or the *idea* of *Generic* & *Gimple* representations, even if of course they all have evolved significantly and recently).

Likewise for the Linux [kernel](http://kernel.org/). It is 24 years old. And probably for [Firefox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox).

And there is no moment where you could say that GCC or the Linux kernel has been *entirely* reimplemented.

My guess is that any large software (e.g. above ten million lines of code, even if we all know that is a poor metric) is never reimplemented. Either it gets *replaced* (by some *new* software with a different *specification*) or it is still continuously maintained, or it simply disappears because nobody cares... (perhaps that happened to strange operating systems on bizarre computers like [Norsk Data 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norsk_Data) - which I have used during my studies at [ENS Cachan](http://www.ens-cachan.fr/) around 1983)

<sup>I *guess* that IBM mainframe Operating Systems (from [OS/360](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS/360_and_successors) to [z/OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z/OS)) is an example of that. On today's rare mainframes, it is possible that some legacy code in them is over 40 years. But of course, most servers are running Linux today, but you cannot say that Linux is a reimplementation of OS/360.</sup>

The reason for that is probably economical; I guess that it is hard to get the capital to rewrite such monsters from scratch. And also because rewriting such monsters would take *years* (and you don't have the guarantee that the result would be better). Read Brook's [*Mythical Man Month*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month) book.

Now, surely, over a large amount of time, every software would vanish. I believe that in 100 years, Linux or GCC (and even C or C++ or POSIX) could be forgotten.... But I'll be long dead before.

But I guess that [*technical debt*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) is the word describing the best what you are thinking about.

Comment: A good answer, but the Linux kernel was a reimplementation of software that already existed.  To varying degrees you could say the same about GCC and Firefox.

Comment: But OS/360 was not replaced by some nearly identical clone. That was my main point.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's about software *fit* to its environment and to developer's expectations.

What do I mean by environment: Software that doesn't evolve works with file formats and protocols that gradually come out of fashion. Operating system may be replaced making parts of the codebase seem odd at least even if they somehow still function. Old programs don't know Internet and misses lots of opportunities there.

What do I mean by expectations: Programming language of the software changes it's idioms slowly and ultimately comes out of fashion. Software methodology evolves and even that twenty years ago it was acceptable to write code without tests, it's suspicious at least now. So the perceived quality of twenty years old codebase is much lower in eyes of today's programmer as she cannot work with it in a way she expects.

I don't think there is a magical property that would make well-maintained program loose it's usefulness over time. The ultimate problem is that almost no one understands that "maintenance" doesn't mean just "fix obvious issues", but also "align the code with the changing world continuously". When you just fix obvious problems, you end up with software full of "oh, this is off" behaviours that no one wants to use or develop. And then you will say the code is rotten.